# Rotate Base64 string in React-Native without file

Tags: base64, react-native

I have a signature that gets captured, and on android, I need to rotate this image, but I am not actually saving the image to the device. I get the base64 string. Is there a way that I can rotate the image just using this string? Or do I need to save the image, rotate it, get the base64 from that, then delete the image? I don't work with base64 very often, so if this is a dumb question, I am sorry. I've tried using ImageRotate, but it requires a uri to a file, so I keep getting a noprotocol error.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: base64 is not an image format but just a certain encoding format to encode bytes. Whatever kind of operation has to be done on an base64 encoded image has to be done after decoding and then you have to encode it again.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks! That makes sense. I'll save it and reencode.

Comment: You don't have to save it. You can decode image, access and create a rotated copy of the bitmap (using matrix), and recreate an image from the new bitmap.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

You can put Base64 string directly to image tag in react-native and can rotate this image tag using css.
I have created a simple code for you.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingTop: 50,
  },
  tinyLogo: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
  },
  logo: {
    width: 66,
    height: 58,
  },
});

const encodedBase64 = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADMAAAAzCAYAAAA6oTAqAAAAEXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBwbmdjcnVzaEB1SfMAAABQSURBVGje7dSxCQBACARB+2/ab8BEeQNhFi6WSYzYLYudDQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgZmcvDqYGBgmhivGQYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgYGBgbmQw+P/eMrC5UTVAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';

const DisplayAnImage = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    
      <Image
        style={[styles.logo, {
            transform: [{rotateZ: '20deg'}],
        }]}
        source={{
          uri: `data:image/gif;base64,${encodedBase64}`,
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

export default DisplayAnImage;
```